# Drupal login via Rest server

Tags: jquery, json, drupal, rest, authentication

I'm developing a website who uses an external Drupal for the articles and pages.
The purpose is to show the articles in a website using just html/css/js.

I've added an Rest Server module to the drupal back-end so I can do http requests for retreiving the articles. Now retreiving the articles from the drupal back-end works (see code below). Restdrupal is the name of my site and restendpoint is the name of the Rest server's endpoint (Captian Obvious)

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://127.0.0.1/restdrupal/restendpoint/node.json",
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data) {
              //further code
    }
});
```

Now I want my customer to be able to add some articles, so I need to login first.
I've been searching the internet for days now and tried a million things but nothing worked for me. The latest thing i've tried (with jQuery) was this :

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://127.0.0.1/restdrupal/restendpoint/user/login",
    dataType:'application/json',
    type : 'PUT',
    data : 'Name=myusername&Pass=mypassword',
    success : function(data) {
        //further code
    },
    error:function(data){
           //Error handling
    }
});
```

I've also changed the PUT into POST...

The response i'm getting is (no mather what I do) the same :

```
406 Not Acceptable: Unsupported request content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Could please somebody help me?
Kind regards,
Ceetn

Comment: is anyone able to clarify - is this drupal 6 or 7, and is it services 2 or 3? ta!

Comment: Drupal 7 and services 3.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to enable application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type of your service endpoint.

Do as follows: Services -> Edit Resources -> select tab "Server" -> enable "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and that's it

Comment: This was my problem as well, thanks for posting! This is the first time I've set up services and I completely overlooked that setting.

Comment: How to allow authentication from different URL? If my service is on A.com and I want to login from B.com is it possible and How? I have tryied using `crossDomain: TRUE` in $.ajax and `JSONP` but give me message `access denied for anonymous user`

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution myself. For those who are interested :

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://127.0.0.1/restdrupal/restpoint/user/login.json",
    type : 'post',
    data : 'username=' + encodeURIComponent(username) + '&password=' + encodeURIComponent(password),
    dataType : 'json',
    error : function(data) {
            //error code
    },
    success : function(data) {
        //success code
    }
});
```

Comment: Above code is working fine when I am passing username and password to user/login.json url.

My question is, when we use jQuery instread of PHP/CURL it is automatically add cookie value to browser?

In my case the above code is working fine and login me to site successfully.

But, When I am using the same using PHP/CURL Request it will give me success response with Sess ID and Value but I think not stored as Cookie and do not logged in me to site?

Any Help

Answer (score 1):

might need to enable that parser type?

check this link out. maybe it will help you get some ideas https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3207/simple-rest-request-to-create-nodes