# php file get contents with post data

Tags: php, http, encoding, stream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drupal login via Rest server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535820/drupal-login-via-rest-server)

I have been using this code for file get contents with post data but receiving an error

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://50.116.19.49/rest/user/login.json): failed to open  
stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 406 Not Acceptable: Unsupported request content type 
application/x-www-form-urlencoded in C:\xampp\htdocs\post.php on line 20
```

My code is

```
<?php

$postdata = http_build_query(
array(
    'var1' => 'myuser',
    'var2' => 'pwd'
)
);

$opts = array('http' =>
array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content' => $postdata
)
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('http://50.116.19.49/rest/user/login.json', false,    
$context);

?>
```

Can anybody help in this Thanks in advance.

Comment: try with `$fp = fopen('http://url', 'r', false, $context);`

Comment: also  change `'Content-type: application/json'` as your url ends with `.json`

Comment: diEcho That `content-type` header is for the request and not the response content. As you can see the request is really an urlencoded form. And honestly I don't see how going from `file_get_contents` to `fopen` would change anything. @OP Do you still get this error when you try to read a `.php` file like that?

Comment: I have written fopen syntax above , also i have checked then it gives `Access denied for user anonymous` please pass correct data with key `username` and `password`

Answer (score 2):

we can use curl instead of function file_get_contents($request);
Here is the code of curl :

```
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$request);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

 $xml_response = curl_exec($ch);
```

where $request is your url.

Comment: you also have to set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);`

Comment: Benchmarkinging usually shows that cURL is a better option.

Comment: @Repox benchmarking usually shows that the difference between cURL and fcg is negligible compared to other parts of your application.

Comment: -1 because it does not answer the question at all. The above cURL is for a GET request, while the OP does a POST request.

Answer (score 1):

`file_get_contents` returns `FALSE` on error with the HTTP stream wrapper as well. An error means any error condition with the HTTP response, for example a HTTP status code from the 400 range like [406 Not Acceptable: Unsupported request content type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.7) in your case.

You can disable the *"FALSE on Error"* behavior by setting the [`ignore_errors`HTTP context option](http://www.php.net/context.http) to `TRUE`:

```
'ignore_errors' = TRUE,
```

You will then get the response body of the request as the result in error cases, too.

To obtain the status code itself you can make use of the [special `$http_response_header` variable](http://php.net/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader).

For a discussion of these settings and how to parse response headers, please see [HEAD first with PHP Streams](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/head-first-with-php-streams/). However in your case the response body might already contain more information about the problem.

In your specific problem you need to double check that the encoding of the request is supported by the server. As I don't know your server, I can not say much about that. The reference to the error code might shed some light for you. There seems to be a problem with the *Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded* you are using.

For example as other clever folks on this site have told me, that endpoint is Drupal. If so, the following was suggested in [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8535820/367456):

> You have to enable `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type of your service endpoint.
>
> Do as follows: Services -> Edit Resources -> select tab "Server" -> enable "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and that's it.

Hopefully this is of help to you.

Answer (score 1):

This particular server, as it seems, expects to see JSON in the POST data when you call `/login.json`, so you should rewrite a few things in your code.

1. Change the `$postdata` construction:

   ```
   $postdata = json_encode(array(
       'var1' => 'myuser',
       'var2' => 'pwd'
   ));
   ```
2. Change the `Content-Type` header:

   ```
   $opts = array('http' => array(
       'method'  => 'POST',
       'header'  => 'Content-type: application/json',
       'content' => $postdata
   ));
   ```